# What are constraints on including interactions into logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction

I'm assessing effects of age, gender and speech style on the realization of linguistic forms. All the dependent and independent variables are binary categorical.
My dataset:

[image]

[image]

When I run logistic regression, I get the output with highly significant effects of 2 variables:

[image]

[image]

If I add 3-way interactions to the model, all p values jump to around 1:

[image]

[image]

I'm stumped by this transformation and I wonder what could affect the output so much.
Can the model with 3-way interactions be unreliable?
I read that a big dataset might be needed to assess interactions, otherwise, things can get messy.
The sample of speakers I'm working with is 16. The number of data observations is 1164.

Comment: Could you please show the specific function calls that you invoked for the logistic regression, and a sample of your data? That might help in providing an answer. Note that the standard errors in the interaction model are extremely high.

Comment: Please provide some details of your model--I cannot reproduce these results with the data shown in your plot.  The actual counts are needed.  What is the link function?  What do the 0/1 codes mean for each factor?  Do you mean something special by "linguistic regression"?  How are you handling the correlations likely introduced by having multiple observations per speaker?

Comment: If you have 16 subjects with 1164 total observations you must have have repeated measures. How are you controlling for that ?

Comment: @EdM I added the functions, could you please have a look a them

Comment: @whuber I added the functions and codes for the factors I used, I hope it may clarify the picture

Comment: @Robert Long I'm planning to use random effects for speaker and words. Will it be right?

Comment: You haven't given enough information about your study design to be sure of the details, but in general yes random intercepts are a good way to handle repeated measures.

Answer (score 1):

Although adding interaction terms to a regression model can change coefficient estimates and p-values from those estimated without interactions for several reasons, the spectacular increase in the standard errors suggests that your data suffer from the phenomenon of [perfect separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/separation/info) that can occur in logistic regression. That is, your combination of predictors completely predicts the binary outcome. Then the maximum-likelihood method for fitting the model runs into problems and standard errors of coefficient estimates can be enormous.

It might seem that perfect prediction is a modeling success, but typically results from such a model don't work well on a new data sample. [This discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11109/28500) goes into more detail and suggests ways to deal with perfect separation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't have a clue about such a phenomenon.